# Google Calendar Event Duration Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, google-calendar-api

> I am trying to get the duration of each event from the google calendar
>   api.

Here the code that I tried to print off the duration of the first 20 events in a persons calendar:

```
page_token = None
while True:
    calendar_list = service.calendarList().list(pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for calendar_list_entry in calendar_list['items']:

        print(calendar_list_entry['summary'])

        events_result = service.events().list(calendarId=calendar_list_entry['id'], timeMin=now,
                                              maxResults=20, singleEvents=True,
                                              orderBy='startTime').execute()
        events = events_result.get('items', [])

        if not events:
            print('\tNo upcoming events found.')
        for event in events:
            start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
            end = event['end'].get('dateTime', event['end'].get('date'))
            print(end - start)

    page_token = calendar_list.get('nextPageToken')
    if not page_token:
        break
```

I was wondering was there an easy way to get this information from the google calendar api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out with a bit of research into datetime (I've never really worked much with it) and realised that googles start and end times are in iso standard form.

I fixed it by importing the dateutil.parser package and used the isoparse function to convert iso standard strings into datetime.

```
page_token = None
    while True:
        calendar_list = service.calendarList().list(pageToken=page_token).execute()
        for calendar_list_entry in calendar_list['items']:

            print(calendar_list_entry['summary'])

            events_result = service.events().list(calendarId=calendar_list_entry['id'], timeMin=now,
                                                  maxResults=20, singleEvents=True,
                                                  orderBy='startTime').execute()
            events = events_result.get('items', [])

            if not events:
                print('\tNo upcoming events found.')

            for event in events:
                start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
                end = event['end'].get('dateTime', event['end'].get('date'))

                new_start = dateutil.parser.isoparse(start) # changing the start time to datetime format
                new_end = dateutil.parser.isoparse(end) # changing the end time to datetime format
                print(new_end - new_start)
```